# Q: CoreBluetooth peripheral:didConnect called twice

Tags: core-bluetooth

I am using MacOS 10.14.6 and I see peripheral:didConnect being called twice for the same device every time I call _centralManager?.connect once.  Does anyone know why?  It seems like I get 2 calls to didConnect depending on what device I am connecting to.  Some devices get called once and others get called twice.  The devices I am connecting to are different models so all the advertising and GATT database data are different.  This is my code:

```
func Init(){
    let centralQueue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "centralMsgQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
    let opts = [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: false]
    _centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: centralQueue, options: opts)

  }


  func Open(id: Int) -> Int {
    let i = GetDevice(id: id)
    if (i != -1)
    {
        let uuid = UUID(uuidString:_deviceTable[i].uuid!);
        let data = _centralManager!.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: [uuid!]) as [CBPeripheral]
        if data.count > 0 {
          _deviceTable[i]._periph = data[0]
          _deviceTable[i]._periph?.delegate = self
          _deviceTable[i].conn_status = CONN_STATUS_PENDING
          _centralManager?.connect(_deviceTable[i]._periph!, options: nil)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return -1
    }
    return 0
  }

  func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    let i = GetDevicePeriph(per: peripheral)
    if (i != -1) {
        if (_deviceTable[i].conn_status == CONN_STATUS_PENDING)
        {
            _deviceTable[i].conn_status = CONN_STATUS_DIDCONN
            peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        }
    }
    else {
        _centralManager?.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)
    }
  } // END func centralManager(... didConnect peripheral

  func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
      let peripheralID = peripheral.identifier.uuidString
      let deviceName = (advertisementData as NSDictionary).object(forKey: CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey) as? String
      if (deviceName == "Test"){
        _centralManager?.stopScan()
        let dev = device(_periph: nil, uuid: peripheralID, conn_status: CONN_STATUS_DISCOVERED)
        _deviceTable.append(dev)
      }
}

func Discover() {
self._centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:_scanAllowDuplicates])
}

func Test() {
  Init()
  Discover()
  Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5.0)
  if (_deviceTable.count > 0) {
    Open(0)}
}
```

Comment: I suspect you're actually calling `connect()` somewhere else as well. The above code is missing the discover code, and you can't use `retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:)` to handle the first connection, so I expect there's more code that deals with that case (and probably calls `connect()`). Specifically, there's has to be some code that's writing `_deviceTable` that you're not showing us.

Comment: This code is also buggy because it creates a concurrent queue, but it isn't thread-safe to be called on a concurrent queue. Generally the queue you pass to CBCentralManager should be serial.

Comment: I added the discovery code and changed the queue to serial but still see the same problem.  I noticed I only get 2 didConnect calls for certain devices.  I am still trying to figure out what difference in the devices is causing this.

Comment: This code is very odd. It's not clear if you're requesting duplicates or not (you don't show how `_scanAllowDuplicates` is assigned), and sleeping the main thread this way is really dangerous. It probably isn't the cause, but it points to likely other problems in the code you haven't shown. I strongly suggest starting with known-good code, such as this project, and then making changes to meet your needs from there: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/transferring_data_between_bluetooth_low_energy_devices

Comment: To be a bit more clear from earlier post, by "odd" I mean this is not the normal way that Core Bluetooth is implemented (`retrievePeripherals`, for example, is not usually used for this purpose, even though it may work). Since it's also a very unusual style of Swift (it feels somewhat like transliterated C), it's hard to guess what is in the code we don't see. Starting with a known-good CB implementation and adapting it to your specific issue will let you avoid those problems. Best of luck.

Comment: @jeffdev Did you ever figure out what was going on with your duplicate calls? I am also getting the same situation on the latest version of MacOS Big Sur